# What is the term for the number of components of a vector?

Tags: vectors, coordinate-systems

If we have a vector that can be represented by an $n$-tuple whose elements can have any values like:

$$ \boldsymbol{a} = (a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n)$$

we can call $\boldsymbol{a}$ is an $n$-dimensional vector, or the **dimension** of $\boldsymbol{a}$ is $n$.

However, if some elements of a vector are fixed like:

$$ \boldsymbol{b} = (b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_m, 0, \cdots, 0) $$

$\boldsymbol{b}$ is actually $m$-dimensional, isn't it? In this case, how do we refer to the number of coordinates of $\boldsymbol{b}$, which is larger than $m$?

Comment: If the number of zeros is $n$ then $\mathbf b$ is $m+n$ dimensional.

Comment: The distinction for finite dimension does not make much sense. It's more interesting for infinite null-terminated sequences, I think, but I'm not aware of a name for $\max\{n\mid b_n\neq 0\}$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\mathbf b=(b_1,b_2,\cdots b_m, \underbrace{0,0,\cdots,0}_n)
$$
is a vector with $m+n$ components. Since $n$ components are null, the vector $\mathbf b$ is an element of a subspace of dimension $m$ of a vector space of dimension $m+n$.

Comment: OK. It seems that when we say about "dimension" of something, it will be more precise to talk about vector spaces, instead of vectors.